# AngularJs Memory Leak : scope $$watchers increase even if the watched elements are removed

Tags: angularjs, memory-leaks, listeners

I've got a big issue with my AngularJs application...

I load HTML content from the server (custom forms). 
Of course, that loaded HTML contains some `ng-show`, `ng-click` etc...
So, I $compile it before append in my page.
That's works fine.

BUT, each time I `$compile` the loaded HTML, it adds more `$$watchers` in my scope (certainly the ng-show watchers).

Here a little demo/simulation : http://plnkr.co/edit/6sSazsFAugzE5XmcYkS7

My problem : **that `$$watchers` won't never decrease and cause a memory leak if you click hundreds time on "load some".**

I've tried to `remove()`, `empty()`, `unbind()` my elements (the links) but the $$watchers array just keep growing and never be cleaned.

How can I resolve that issue ? How can I clean useless $$watchers or "uncompile" ?

Thanks for your help !!!

Comment: One more example : http://plnkr.co/edit/860fj4D7mkwRXzBZ1Xrb

Answer (score 2):

Since the new elements are compiled from the same scope and on the same element, the watchers are never removed.

All watchers are removed when their scope is destroyed (`scope.$destroy()`) which happens automatically when the element is removed. However your element is never removed, you keep replacing its HTML with new nodes.

A clean way to avoid that would be to avoid recompiling every new links, but instead generate a dynamic `ng-repeat` list.

Otherwise, if you want to keep your code, you can create a new scope for your element every time your compile it. This way, when recompiling it, the previous scope is destroyed and all its watchers removed.

You can see that in action here. All I have done is replace `scope` by `scope.$new()` in the compile call so that a new scope is set to the element every time:

http://plnkr.co/edit/PvUAYyb0IUoaT3dVmpGM?p=preview

PS: that was an interesting use case that I never faced though, it can contribute to the Angular community :-)

Comment: Are you sure that the "new Scope" will be automatically destroyed when the div will be emptied ?

Comment: Not when emptied, but when recompiled. And honestly no, I have no proof of that, but that answer your particular problem when the number of watchers increase. You can now do profiling to see if there is still any memory leak. If that was me, I would not compile at all and do it properly with ng-repeat.

Comment: @floribon your response helped me fixing a very similar issue THANK YOU!! but the memory leak was still there. After some struggling I managed to resolve it and created a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

To properly destroy the `scope` of your compiled element you need to do a `scope.$destroy()`. My proposed solution is to create an inherited scope and destroy it afterwards:

```
    // if there was already an inherited scope, destroy it properly with $destroy()
    if (scope.inheritedScope) scope.inheritedScope.$destroy();
    // create new inherited scope every time 
    scope.inheritedScope = scope.$new(false);
    // use it in the compile
    $compile(element.contents())(scope.inheritedScope);
```

Fork of your code with this solution:
http://plnkr.co/edit/fOOHUGesbHYRiRWeLwKC

Replacing the HTML with `element.html` and only doing a `scope.$new` is not enough. I ran into a very similar situation with a more complex directive. Once replaced, this directive was still producing errors, so I know it was still somewhere in memory.

Comment: Indeed that's an addition. But rather than storing a scope inside another one (good luck to find memory leaks doing that), you can just do `element.scope().$destroy();` as angular binds a scope directly into its html node.